# Can not remove cube in UDK

Tags: udk

For some reason, I can't move or remove an 'invisible' cube which is on my map.
I searched on Google to find a solution but somehow I still can't remove it.

The cube looks like this:
http://screencloud.net/v/uNyz

In Brush Wireframe: http://screencloud.net/v/3C0c

In Wireframe: screencloud.net/v/oGBj

As you can see, I want to delete the brown cube. Selecting it and pressing the DEL button won't do anything.

So, how do you delete the brown cube?

---

EDIT:
Seriously, I wrote this post a few minutes ago and I found the solution. However, I still don't know how to delete the brown cube.

Comment: http://forums.epicgames.com/threads/764831-How-do-I-delete-this

Comment: If you've found the solution, consider writing an answer describing what you did and then accepting that answer. It helps with the organization of the site and it may help future visitors who find your thread through web searches for this kind of problem.

Answer (score 1):

The "brown cube" that you are referring to sounds like it's the builder brush. It is commonly referred to as red and it can be various shapes depending on your last brush setting. You can toggle it's display with the 'B' key.

You may also be referring to a BSP wireframe, in which case you must Ctrl+Shift+click to select it unless you are in a wireframe viewmode.

Answer (score 1):

This is a common mistake for many beginner UDK users. The brown cube is probably the builder brush, a very useful tool for creating meshes that physically affect your character in UDK. *(If you are creating a more complicated project, I would strongly recommend either avoiding them or converting them to 'Static Meshes' - see the referenced tutorial.)* The brown cube is important lots of the time - if you hide it by pressing B, know that you can bring it back by pressing B again.

It could also be a BSP wireframe. (This is something that has been created by the builder brush.) If the above does not work, you can then go into wireframe mode, click on the frame of the 'brown' cube, and press 'Del'/'Delete' on your keyboard (or right click and select delete.) Of course, it is unlikely that it is a BSP wireframe as it would probably appear with its default material - checkered blue and white.

If you are a beginner UDK user, I strongly recommend "Brainspace Showcase"'s [UDK tutorials](http://m.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLTvnj29_ZQicRj8NB1rN8tvkLNSIe1v_p). These were very helpful for me.